# Migrate NativeScript 6.5.1 to 8.1.4 problems with TextField of Nativescript-vue and WebPack 5

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-cli

When try to migrate NS 6.5.1 to NS 8.1.4 TextField fail.

I use:

- @nativescript-cli@8.1.4
- @nativescript/core@8.1.5
- Node v16.13.0
- NPM v8.1.0

After ns clean I execute ns doctor:

```
$ ns doctor
Error while loading nativescript-cloud is: Default commands should be required before child commands
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.1.4 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 8.1.5 version and is up to date.
✖ Component @nativescript/ios is not installed.
✔ Component @nativescript/android has 8.1.1 version and is up to date.
```

When Run app:

```
$ ns run android --env.development --env.api=staging --log trace --env.android
Successfully synced application com.-.app on device d4dde974.
Will emit event runOnDeviceStarted with data {
  projectDir: '/home/xavier/PhpstormProjects/crmhex-app',
  deviceIdentifier: 'd4dde974',
  applicationIdentifier: 'com.-.app'
}
JS: {NSVue (Vue: 2.6.12 | NSVue: 2.9.0)} -> CreateElement(Frame)
....
```

#### The app open but when if focus on TextField console do **error**:

```
JS: Received discarded exception: 
JS: Calling js method afterTextChanged failed
JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

My Package.json actually migration attempt is:

```
{
  "name": "-",
  "main": "app/main.js",
  "version": "0.2.3",
  "description": "A native application built with NativeScript-Vue",
  "author": "-",
  "license": "MIT",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": {
      "ios": "com.-.app",
      "android": "com.-.app"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/localize": "^5.0.4",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "@sergeymell/nativescript-svg": "^1.1.2",
    "@teammaestro/nativescript-svg": "^1.0.1",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio": "^5.0.1",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "^4.1.3",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.26",
    "lodash.chunk": "^4.2.0",
    "lokijs": "^1.5.12",
    "nativescript-advanced-permissions": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-applozic-chat-fork": "^2.2.0",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.4",
    "nativescript-background-http": "^4.2.1",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^7.0.1",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-email": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "^7.0.2",
    "nativescript-http-formdata": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-intl": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^2.0.2",
    "nativescript-mediafilepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-secure-storage": "^2.6.0",
    "nativescript-ui-gauge": "^8.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.9.0",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-vue-navigator": "^0.2.0",
    "nativescript-webview-interface": "^1.4.3",
    "nativescript-windowed-modal": "^7.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-cli": "^2.9.6",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0",
    "vuex-extensions": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "prettier-eslint": "^10.1.1",
    "sass": "~1.39.0",
    "tns-android": "6.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "chmod +x ./entitlements.sh",
    "postinstall": "./entitlements.sh & patch-package",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test",
    "lint-autofix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test --fix",
    "eslint-check": "eslint --print-config .eslintrc.js | eslint-config-prettier-check"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js actually migration attempt is:

```
// New from migration
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");
const {resolve, sep, join} = require("path");

const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const NsVueTemplateCompiler = require("nativescript-vue-template-compiler");

const {exec} = require("child_process");
const countryFiles = require("./lib/copy-country-files");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    //Copy configuration file for applozic theme to platform android
    if (env.android) {
        exec('cp -Rf app/App_Resources/Android/applozic-settings.json platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/applozic-settings.json', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Configured applozic theme!');
        });
        exec('cp -Rf app/App_Resources/Android/FcmListenerService.java platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/tns/FcmListenerService.java', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Configured applozic notifications!');
        });
    }

    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other android app components here.
    const appComponents = env.appComponents || [];
    appComponents.push(...[
        "@nativescript/core/ui/frame",
        "@nativescript/core/ui/frame/activity",
    ]);

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios" || env.platform || 'android');
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const platforms = ["ios", "android"];
    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    if (env.platform) {
        platforms.push(env.platform);
    }

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    //const dist = resolve(projectRoot, webpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file.
        appPath = "app",
        appResourcesPath = "app/App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot
        production, // --env.production
        report, // --env.report
        hmr, // --env.hmr
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hiddenSourceMap, // --env.hiddenSourceMap
        unitTesting, // --env.unitTesting
        verbose, // --env.verbose
        snapshotInDocker, // --env.snapshotInDocker
        skipSnapshotTools, // --env.skipSnapshotTools
        compileSnapshot, // --env.compileSnapshot
        country, // --env.country
    } = env;

    const useLibs = compileSnapshot;
    const isAnySourceMapEnabled = !!sourceMap || !!hiddenSourceMap;

    const mode = production ? "production" : "development"

    if (country) {
        countryFiles.checkCountryFiles(country);
    }

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    webpack.mergeWebpack({
        mode: 'production',
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
                http: false,
                https: false,
                timers: false,
                setImmediate: false,
                fs: false,
                __dirname: false,

                url: false,
                zlib: false,
                tty: false,
                util: false,
                url: false,
                assert: false,
                stream: false,
                os: false,
                fileSystem: false
            }
        }
    })

    /*const projectRoot = __dirname;
    const appPath = "app";
    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const alias = env.alias || {};
    alias['~'] = appFullPath;
    alias['@'] = appFullPath;
    alias['vue'] = 'nativescript-vue';
    alias['Models'] = appFullPath + '/imports/models';
    alias['Components'] = appFullPath + '/imports/components';
    alias['Filters'] = appFullPath + '/imports/filters';
    alias['Services'] = appFullPath + '/imports/services';
    alias['Constants'] = appFullPath + '/imports/constants';
    alias['Exceptions'] = appFullPath + '/imports/exceptions';
    alias['Mixins'] = appFullPath + '/imports/mixins';
    alias['Utils'] = appFullPath + '/utils';*/

    webpack.chainWebpack(
        config => {
        // change the "@" alias to "app/libs"
            config.resolve.alias.set('@', resolve(__dirname, 'app'))
            config.resolve.alias.set('~', resolve(__dirname, 'app'))
            config.resolve.alias.set('vue', 'nativescript-vue')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Models', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/models')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Components', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/components')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Filters', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/filters')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Services', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/services')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Constants', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/constants')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Exceptions', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/exceptions')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Mixins', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/imports/mixins')
            config.resolve.alias.set('Utils', resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/utils')
            config.resolve.alias.set('tns-core-modules', "@nativescript/core")
            config.plugin('VueLoaderPlugin')
            config.plugin('DefinePlugin').tap(args => {
                Object.assign(args[0], {
                    'API_ENV': JSON.stringify(env.api),
                    'TNS_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
                })
                return args
            })
            /*config.module.rule([join(appFullPath, entryPath + ".js"), join(appFullPath, entryPath + ".ts")]).use('nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader').loader('nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader').options({
                modules: appComponents
            }),*/

            /*config.module.rule('app/css').use('nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader').loader('nativescript-dev-webpack/css2json-loader').options({
                useForImports: true
            }),
            config.module.rule('app/scss').use('nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader').loader('nativescript-dev-webpack/css2json-loader').options({
                useForImports: true
            }),*/
            /*config.module.rule('app/css').exclude.add('app/css').use('nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader').loader('nativescript-dev-webpack/apply-css-loader.js').options({
                url: false
            }),
            config.module.rule('app/scss').exclude.add('app/scss').use('nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader').loader('nativescript-dev-webpack/apply-css-loader.js').options({
                url: false
            }),*/
            config.module.rule('js').use('babel-loader').loader('babel-loader')
            /*config.module.rule('ts').use('ts-loader').loader('ts-loader').options({
                appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                compilerOptions: {
                    declaration: false
                }
            }),*/
            config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').options({
                compiler: NsVueTemplateCompiler,
            })
            // config.module.rule('html').use('html-loader').loader('html-loader') // TODO fix error SCSS {
        })

    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);


    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```